# Measuring delays using .NET libraries

Tags: .net, time, timer, timedelay

I am building an application in .NET (not important what language, it is a language of the framework).
I need to count how much time passes from an instruction to another. I need, so, to measure time.

How to do this using .NET libraries? Which one is the right namespace/class to use? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` is probably what you want to use for this purpose, but keep in mind that while `Stopwatch` is highly *granular* it is not especially accurate for long time periods.  For example, if you start a `Stopwatch` and let it run for exactly 24 hours (as measured by an independent clock or the computer's system clock), it will show an elapsed time of 24 hours *plus* 5-10 seconds (*not* milliseconds).

So, if you want to measure very short durations, use `Stopwatch`.  If the durations you wish to measure are longer (on the order of a few minutes or more), you should instead make calls to `DateTime.UtcNow` at the start and end of your sequence, and calculate the difference as a `Timespan`.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class. An example can be found on the linked MSDN page.